# Why pointwise convergence does not imply uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

**Definition 1.** Suppose that $\left(f_{n}\right)$ is a sequence of functions $f_{n}: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ pointwise on $A$ if, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{x,\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$n>N_{x,\epsilon}$ implies that $\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in A$.

**Definition 2.** Suppose that $\left(f_{n}\right)$ is a sequence of functions $f_{n}: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $A$ if, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$n>N_{\epsilon}$ implies that $\left|f_{n}(x)-f(x)\right|<\epsilon$ for all $x \in A$.

Suppose in definition $2$ we take $N_{\epsilon}=\max(N_{x,\epsilon})$ this does not means  that pointwise convergence implies uniform convergence?

Comment: Why should $\max(N_{x,\epsilon})$ exist?

Comment: @Desperado for all $x$ exist a $N_{x,\epsilon}$ so there should exist a maximum between them

Comment: No, for example the maximum of $\mathbb N$ does not exist.

Comment: What if $N_{\varepsilon, x}=\lfloor 1/x \rfloor$ for $x\in (0;1)$?

Comment: A good example is $A=(0;1)$ and $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1,& x\in (0;1/n), \\ 0,& \text{else}. \end{cases}$$ Then $f(x)=0$. Check what $N_{1/2, x}$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\{N_{x,\varepsilon}\mid x\in A\}$ is an infinite set (in general), and therefore you cannot be sure that it has a maximum (or even that it has an upper bound).

If, for instance, $A=[0,1]$, if$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x=1/n\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$and if $\varepsilon=\frac12$, you can take$$N_{x,\varepsilon}=\begin{cases}n+1&\text{ if }x=1/n\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb N\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$It is then clear that $\{N_{x,\varepsilon}\mid x\in A\}$ has no upper bound.

Comment: what you mean is this we can this of $\{N_{x,\varepsilon}\mid x\in A\}$ as a function from $R$ to $N$  and since $N$ is unbounded that means that $N_{x,\varepsilon}$ is unbounded

Comment: No. The set $\{N_{x,\varepsilon}\mid x\in A\}$ is just a set of natural numbers. And what I am saying is  that, in general, that is has no upper bound. In particular, you cannot talk about its maximum.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to understand a definition is by example. And one of the simplest example to see the difference between pointwise and uniform converges is -

$f_n:[0, 1]\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $f_n(x) =x^n$

Then, $f_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1] $ where $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in[0,1)\\ 1 & x=1\end{cases}$

But $f_n$ doesn't converge to $f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$ (Prove!)

For $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, what $N_{\epsilon}$ works?